# What is the maximum number of devices I can add to a firebase group?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to have a feature in which I want to send bulk notifications to a segment of users. I was planning to use the Firebase Group feature to send messages to the user segments. I will have around 200k users in a segment. The problem is, I read somewhere that only 20 members are allowed in a group. Can I use groups for user segmentation? If not, what is the alternative? If I use topics, can I get the number of successful deliveries and failed deliveries? Please help, I am not very experienced in this. The code is in Symfony, PHP.